# Hexomino IQ Test

Tags: visual, geometry

[image]

Which one from 5 Hexominos fits the fifth box.
Give us your reason why you choose it.

Comment: I hope you're not outsourcing your IQ testing to us...

Comment: @mr23ceec : No, I create it myself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The hexomino that fits in the box is:

> D

Because:

> The four hexominos in the boxes are [cube nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(polyhedron)), i.e. they can be folded along the lines so that the squares form the faces of a cube. D is the only one of the choices that is also a cube net.

Comment: I guessed the "Because", I just couldn't be arsed to spend any more time on it! Did you do it mentally?

Comment: Nice job, though it would've been more fitting if @hexomino got this one!

Answer (score 5):

> C

Because:

> imagine a grid on each hexamino going from a:1 in the top left corner to c:5 in the bottom right (or f:6, but since there's nothing beyond c line or the 5 line, we won't need it.) Every hexomino in the example has 3 cells in common, a:3, b3 and b4. Of the 3 choices presented, only C satifies this rule.

Here's a picture:

> upon actually editing I realised they aren't as aligned as appears at a glance, but here it is:[image]

I'm joking, of course, Wu33o's answer "clicks", in a way this one does not, but you might want to eliminate the ambiguity if it's for anything offcicial.

Comment: Ok, your reason is acceptable. To make the test official I have to spin C, to avoid double interpretation.